# Impossible to get property from mongoose object

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm having a strange behaviour with mongoose. When I `console.log` the result object, I see that the property is here, but when I try to get just the desired value like `console.log(obj.propt)`it return undefined.

```
ServerModel.findOne(function (err, server) {
    if (err) {
        return console.error(err);
    }

    console.log(server);
    // output:
    // {_id: 55ead0eb4105b7df958256af,
    // name: 'st1',
    // ip: '57.29.42.241',
    // capacity: 0,
    // totalUsed: 0,
    // state: true }

    console.log(server.ip);
    // output: undefined

    console.log(server.name);
    // output: st1

    // but that works if I use the toObject method
    var srvr = server.toObject();

    var serverAddress = srvr.ip;
    // serverAddress is 57.29.42.241
});
```

Strangely, it works if I use the `.toObject` method. I must have missed something. Does anyone has an explanation for that?

Comment: Oh I'm so dumb… At least I hope it might be helpful for some other absent-minded like me! Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will happen when a field is present in the MongoDB document, but not defined in your Mongoose schema.

So be sure to define it in your `ServerModel` schema as

```
ip: String
```

Or, to access it even though it's not defined in your schema, use the [`get`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#document_Document-get) method:

```
console.log(server.get('ip'));
```